# Not able to append data in a text file

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I've a try and catch block in my code. From the catch block I'm calling a method to append the exception message

```
catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage().toString();
            String errorMessage = "Exception ------ Error ----- " + error;
            System.out.println("The Error Message: " + errorMessage);
            appendLog(errorMessage, log_file);
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Here is the appendlog method

```
public void appendLog(String text, File log_file) {
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(log_file, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out = new PrintWriter(bw);
            out.println(text);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

So, whenever the execution comes at "bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);" it breaks out of the method and gives a null pointer exception.

Please note I've other methods calling the same appendLog method to append data to the same file.

Comment: are you certain that `log_file` is not `null` when passed in?

Comment: @14jbella Yes, I'm certain the log_file is not null

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain?